# I need to change RAM without affecting Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ram

I have installed Ubuntu in VirtualBox and installed a few applications in Ubuntu. But my Windows RAM size is 2 GB. I want to change it to 4 GB RAM. Will doing this erase all the data in Ubuntu?

Comment: RAM is not the same as disk space.  RAM is volatile and used only when machine is in operation (ie. no data is stored there when off; it's stored on hdd/ssd). Changing RAM sizes should only change speed of operation (less swapping of RAM to disk).  A VM though in Virtualbox can not be given more RAM than the host has (ie. if host OS has 2gb, you can't give VM 4gb); so I may be missing something in language sorry.

Comment: First of fall RAM is not actually used for data storage it's basically used for faster processing.Your data stored in Ubuntu has no relevance with your host RAM in your case windows.And by the way RAM is temporary memory so it stores only temporary data

Comment: Yes, you can shutdown Ubuntu, then change the settings to increase your RAM. But what problem are you trying to solve? Adding more RAM to the VM may not be the best solution. I'd recommend leaving your RAM at 2048, and if you've got multiple CPU's in your computer, setting your CPU count to 2. In Ubuntu, type `free -h` in the `terminal`, and edit your question with that output.

Answer (score 4):

The hardware resources of a guest OS that is running in a virtual machine are virtual too, not physical. For example an Ubuntu guest OS that uses 2GB or 4GB of RAM gets its RAM from the VirtualBox application which in turn uses some of the physical RAM of the computer that it is running on the same as all other applications in the host OS do. Another consequence of this is that the virtual RAM allocated to the guest OS does not affect the performance of the host OS in any way except when the guest OS is running.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't affect your data. Simple answer.