# I Have 1.6Ghz Processor. What Happen if i keep run to install ubuntu desktop on virtual box

Tags: system-installation

Hello Everyone I am a new user and beginner in Linux. I want to install Ubuntu desktop on VirtualBox. I have 4GB of RAM and 17GB of unallocated space. I have a 1.6GHz processor.

What happens with my laptop if I install Ubuntu desktop on VirtualBox? Will my laptop blow up?

Comment: Ubuntu won't run well on your 4GB RAM if you're installing it on VirtualBox. You need to have 8GB of RAM. Alas, nothing will blow. :)

Comment: Thank You Sarru.

Comment: No worries. You can have Linux Mint that will run pretty well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to change RAM without affecting Ubuntu in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/1182089/) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Most of your experience will be on the slow side, but you can try out Lubuntu in virtualbox to make it a bit better.  Another way of trying Ubuntu is to use a live USB and/or do a  full install of Ubuntu to a USB.  You get to try Ubuntu using the full 4GBs of ram this way.

Answer (score 0):

No your laptop will be fine. Virtual box is like an any other normal program. The question is that to run VM you need to assign some RAM to it, which you have only 4 GB, luckily linux is not so power hungry. Actually your experience will mostly depend on type of your laptop drive (is it HDD or SSD). By the way with this specs it's a good choice to use Ubuntu as main OS because of it's speed.